# How to bind ng-model to the "value" of selected item for ui-select

Tags: angularjs

Please check out the following plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fc9XcyyYGtAk0aGVV35t?p=preview

```
  <ui-select ng-model="fm.countryCode" id="countryCode">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a country...">{{$select.selected.label}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="item in countries | filter: $select.search" value="{{$select.selected.value}}">
          <div ng-bind-html="item.label | highlight: $select.search"></div>
          <small ng-bind-html="item.value | highlight: $select.search"></small>
      </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

I'm trying to get ui-select to set fm.countryCode to the value of the selected item. Currently it's just setting fm.countryCode to the whole country item. For example if I select Afghanistan, fm.countryCode will be set to {"value":"AF","label":"Afghanistan"}. What I want is "AF".

Do I have to set up a $watch to achieve this or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EoBl4YZ6QfnJdHfOMM10?p=preview take a look

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change your ui-select to:

```
<ui-select ng-model="fm.countryCode" id="countryCode">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a country...">{{$select.selected.label}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item.value as item in countries | filter: $select.search" value="{{$select.selected.value}}">
      <div ng-bind-html="item.label | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small ng-bind-html="item.value | highlight: $select.search"></small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

This will take item.value as the complete item, instead of both value and label.

So the repeat part: `<ui-select-choices repeat="item.value as item in countries` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
fm.countryCode = {{fm.countryCode}}
```

for

```
fm.countryCode = {{fm.countryCode.value}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok replace

```
 fm.countryCode = {{fm.countryCode}}
```

to

```
 fm.countryCode = {{fm.countryCode.value}}
```

See in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/EoBl4YZ6QfnJdHfOMM10?p=preview

Comment: I don't think his eventual goal is to just show the value of fm.countryCode on his html.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution IMO would be:

changing this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="fm.countryCode" id="countryCode">
     <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a country...">{{$select.selected.label}}</ui-select-match>
     <ui-select-choices repeat="item in countries | filter: $select.search" value="{{$select.selected.value}}">
              <div ng-bind-html="item.label | highlight: $select.search"></div>
              <small ng-bind-html="item.value | highlight: $select.search"></small>
     </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
```

to this:

```
<select ng-options="country.value as country.label for country in countries" ng-model="fm.countryCode"> </select>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JrgnTH?p=preview)